# Set props on react class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a third party component.
I have two classes named `Parent` and `Child`. In `Parent` component I use that third party component which accepts a class name as a prop and renders in itself.
So the parent component looks like this:

```
render(){
  return (
    <div className="section">
      <Select
        placeholder={placeholder}
        valueComponent={Child}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

What I want to do is to pass some props to Child component, but I've always done this like `<Child someProp="prop"/>`.
Is there any way to pass props to `Child` component in this manner?

Comment: I assume `Select` is the third-party component in question. Does it specify that child component must be passed via `props.valueComponent`? Usually children components are passed in with `this.props.children` like `<Select><Child/></Select>`

Comment: @Dan yes ``Select`` is that 3rd party lib. no component ``Child`` should be passed in ``valueComponent`` prop

Comment: um...what? So `Child` should not be passed in as `valueComponent`?

Comment: no it should be passed as ``valueComponent``, it shouldn't be passed like ``<Select><Child/></Child>``

Comment: you should check the documentation of the third party component. NavigatorIOS of React native follows this style. They have a passProps property which passes props to the child component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the `Select` library provides a way to do that. In case, you could always use a wrapper component:

```
// Create a child wrapper component and pass it to Select.
function ChildWrapper(props) {
  return <Child {...props} someProp="prop" />;
}

render(){
  return (
    <div className="section">
      <Select
        placeholder={placeholder}
        valueComponent={ChildWrapper}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks, don't know why didn't think of a hoc for this.